# Buildroot in WSL vs. Antimalware Service Executable

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, buildroot

I'm attempting to build an embedded Raspberry Pi Linux OS using Buildroot-2019.02.2 in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). The compilation keeps failing and I have no idea where to start to fix it. I also tried with the latest Git version of Buildroot and had the same problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Last 100 lines or so of output:

```
  CC librt/spawn_faction_addclose.os
  CC librt/mq_timedsend.os
  CC librt/spawn_faction_addopen.os
  CC librt/mq_send.os
  CC librt/mq_timedreceive.os
  CC librt/clock_gettime.os
  CC librt/shm.os
  CC librt/clock_getcpuclockid.os
  CC librt/spawn_faction_adddup2.os
  CC librt/mq_getsetattr.os
  CC librt/spawn.os
  CC librt/clock_nanosleep.os
  CC librt/dso_handle.os
  CC librt/mq_open.os
  CC librt/mq_unlink.os
  CC libintl/libintl.os
libintl/libintl.c:81:13: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 const char *_nl_expand_alias () { return NULL; }
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CC libc/misc/internals/__uClibc_main.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/fork.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_pthread_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_multiple_threads.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/register-atfork.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/unregister-atfork.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getpid.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/jmp-unwind.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/alloca_cutoff.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/libc-cancellation.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/arm/libc-tls.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/generic/dl-tls.os
  AS libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/libc-aeabi_read_tp.os
  CC libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/aeabi_lcsts.os
  CC libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/aeabi_math.os
  AS libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/aeabi_sighandlers.os
  CC libc/misc/elf/dl-support.os
  CC libc/misc/elf/dl-core.os
In file included from ./include/bits/waitstatus.h:72:0,
                 from ./include/stdlib.h:44,
                 from ./ldso/include/ldso.h:33,
                 from libc/misc/elf/../../../ldso/ldso/dl-symbols.c:18,
                 from libc/misc/elf/dl-core.c:18:
./ldso/include/dl-syscall.h: In function '_dl_pread':
./ldso/include/dl-syscall.h:169:69: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
 turn __syscall_pread(fd, buf, count, 0, __LONG_LONG_PAIR((offset >> 32), (offset & 0xffffffff)));
                                                                  ^
./include/endian.h:52:39: note: in definition of macro '__LONG_LONG_PAIR'
 # define __LONG_LONG_PAIR(HI, LO) LO, HI
                                       ^~
  CC libc/misc/elf/dl-iterate-phdr.os
In file included from ./include/elf.h:29:0,
                 from ./include/link.h:24,
                 from libc/misc/elf/dl-iterate-phdr.c:15:
./ldso/include/dl-syscall.h: In function '_dl_pread':
./ldso/include/dl-syscall.h:169:69: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
 turn __syscall_pread(fd, buf, count, 0, __LONG_LONG_PAIR((offset >> 32), (offset & 0xffffffff)));
                                                                  ^
./include/endian.h:52:39: note: in definition of macro '__LONG_LONG_PAIR'
 # define __LONG_LONG_PAIR(HI, LO) LO, HI
                                       ^~
  CC libc/stdlib/atexit.os
  CC libc/stdlib/system.os
  CC ldso/libdl/libdl.os
In file included from ./include/bits/waitstatus.h:72:0,
                 from ./include/stdlib.h:44,
                 from ./ldso/include/ldso.h:33,
                 from ldso/libdl/libdl.c:40:
./ldso/include/dl-syscall.h: In function '_dl_pread':
./ldso/include/dl-syscall.h:169:69: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
 turn __syscall_pread(fd, buf, count, 0, __LONG_LONG_PAIR((offset >> 32), (offset & 0xffffffff)));
                                                                  ^
./include/endian.h:52:39: note: in definition of macro '__LONG_LONG_PAIR'
 # define __LONG_LONG_PAIR(HI, LO) LO, HI
                                       ^~
  AS ldso/ldso/arm/resolve.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_atfork.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/pthread_once.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_attr_getaffinity.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_attr_setaffinity.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_getaffinity.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_setaffinity.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_getcpuclockid.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_kill.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_mutex_cond_lock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_yield.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_post.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_timedwait.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_trywait.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_wait.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_sigqueue.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/lowlevellock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/lowlevelrobustlock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/arm/pthread_spin_lock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/arm/pthread_spin_trylock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_barrier_destroy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_barrier_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_barrier_wait.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_cond_broadcast.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_cond_signal.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_cond_timedwait.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_cond_wait.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_rwlock_rdlock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_rwlock_timedrdlock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_rwlock_unlock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_rwlock_wrlock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_sigmask.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_spin_destroy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_spin_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread_spin_unlock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pt-sigaction.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/tpp.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_getstackaddr.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutex_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_testcancel.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_setstackaddr.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_timedjoin.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_rwlock_trywrlock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_barrierattr_getpshared.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setresgid.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_gettype.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setreuid.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setcancelstate.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_getschedparam.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_kill_other_threads.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_settype.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_seteuid.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_barrierattr_destroy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/vars.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pt-cleanup.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_barrierattr_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setresuid.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutex_unlock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/cleanup_defer.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutex_timedlock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutex_consistent.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/events.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/cleanup.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_getschedpolicy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_tryjoin.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_setschedpolicy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_getname.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_rwlockattr_getkind_np.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_equal.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_setguardsize.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_detach.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_getstacksize.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setname.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutex_trylock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/herrno.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_setstacksize.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/cleanup_defer_compat.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_getdetachstate.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_cancel.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_rwlock_destroy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_condattr_getclock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sem_unlink.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_rwlock_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_rwlockattr_destroy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_condattr_setclock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_key_create.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setschedparam.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_rwlockattr_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_destroy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_getspecific.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_rwlockattr_getpshared.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_exit.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_getconcurrency.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setspecific.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_cond_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setconcurrency.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sem_getvalue.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setregid.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_getguardsize.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_self.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_barrierattr_setpshared.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setschedprio.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_condattr_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_getstack.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_getschedparam.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_condattr_getpshared.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/unwind.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_setstack.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_condattr_setpshared.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_cond_destroy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sem_destroy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_getprioceiling.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_getinheritsched.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_setschedparam.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setegid.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sem_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_getscope.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_setprioceiling.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_setinheritsched.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/cleanup_routine.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_rwlock_tryrdlock.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_attr_setscope.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutex_getprioceiling.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_getattr_np.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutex_setprioceiling.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_key_delete.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_create.os
In file included from libpthread/nptl/pthread_create.c:48:0:
libpthread/nptl/allocatestack.c: In function 'allocate_stack':
libpthread/nptl/allocatestack.c:602:6: warning: label 'mprot_error' defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
      mprot_error:
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_join.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/cleanup_compat.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_destroy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_setcanceltype.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sem_open.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_init.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_condattr_destroy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/cancellation.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sem_close.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_mutex_destroy.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/errno_location.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mq_notify.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_create.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_delete.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_getoverr.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_gettime.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_routines.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_settime.os
  CC libpthread/nptl/sysdeps/pthread/librt-cancellation.os
  AR cr lib/libc.a
  STRIP -x -R .note -R .comment lib/libc.a
  CC libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1.o
  AR cr lib/uclibc_nonshared.a
  STRIP -x -R .note -R .comment lib/uclibc_nonshared.a
  AR cr libc/libc_so.a
  STRIP -x -R .note -R .comment libc/libc_so.a
  CC libpthread/nptl/pthread_atfork.oS
  AR cr lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
  STRIP -x -R .note -R .comment lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
  LD libuClibc-1.0.31.so
./lib/ld-uClibc.so.1: warning: multiple common of `_dl_internal_error_number'
libc/libc_so.a(libdl.oS): warning: previous common is here
./lib/ld-uClibc.so.1: warning: multiple common of `_dl_error_number'
libc/libc_so.a(libdl.oS): warning: previous common is here
./lib/ld-uClibc.so.1: warning: multiple common of `_dl_free_function'
libc/libc_so.a(libdl.oS): warning: previous common is here
./lib/ld-uClibc.so.1: warning: multiple common of `_dl_malloc_function'
libc/libc_so.a(libdl.oS): warning: previous common is here
libc/libc_so.a(dl-iterate-phdr.oS): In function `dl_iterate_phdr':
dl-iterate-phdr.c:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `_dl_phnum'
dl-iterate-phdr.c:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `_dl_phdr'
libc/libc_so.a(__uClibc_main.oS): In function `__uClibc_init':
__uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `__libc_setup_tls'
libc/libc_so.a(__uClibc_main.oS): In function `__uClibc_fini':
__uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `__fini_array_start'
__uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `__fini_array_end'
libc/libc_so.a(__uClibc_main.oS): In function `__uClibc_main':
__uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x21c): undefined reference to `_dl_aux_init'
__uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x560): undefined reference to `__preinit_array_end'
__uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x564): undefined reference to `__preinit_array_start'
__uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x56c): undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
__uClibc_main.c:(.text+0x570): undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
libc/libc_so.a(libdl.oS): In function `_dl_do_reloc':
libdl.c:(.text+0xfac): undefined reference to `_dl_allocate_static_tls'
libc/libc_so.a(libdl.oS): In function `_dl_load_elf_shared_library':
libdl.c:(.text+0x1c34): undefined reference to `_dl_next_tls_modid'
libdl.c:(.text+0x1e1c): undefined reference to `_dl_linux_resolve'
/mnt/e/work-current/buildroot-2019.02.2/output/host/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/7.4.0/../../../../arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/bin/ld: lib/libuClibc-1.0.31.so: hidden symbol `__fini_array_end' isn't defined
/mnt/e/work-current/buildroot-2019.02.2/output/host/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/7.4.0/../../../../arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
libc/Makefile.in:77: recipe for target 'lib/libc.so' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libc.so] Error 1
package/pkg-generic.mk:238: recipe for target '/mnt/e/work-current/buildroot-2019.02.2/output/build/uclibc-1.0.31/.stamp_built' failed
make[1]: *** [/mnt/e/work-current/buildroot-2019.02.2/output/build/uclibc-1.0.31/.stamp_built] Error 2
Makefile:84: recipe for target '_all' failed
make: *** [_all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, Windows is not a supported build environment. With the upcoming Windows changes it could perhaps be made to work, but in general, the best environment to develop a Linux system on is Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by disabling the ‘Antimalware Service Executable’ process, part of Windows Defender, that was messing with the build process.

1. Run ‘regedit’ (Windows key + R)
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender
3. Create registry entry named DisableAntiSpyware, New > DWORD (32 bit) Value and set to 1
4. Reboot

Comment: Reference: [DisableAntiSpyware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/security-malware-windows-defender-disableantispyware)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that after solving this problem I ran into other issues using Buildroot in WSL, so much so that I have now switched to an Ubuntu virtual machine using OracleVM.

Comment: That's probably your best bet. Unlike a virtual machine, WSL does not provide a complete Linux kernel or OS environment. It is more a wrapper that provides the ability to run a shell and tools on that shell. BUT... [Bad News! Windows 10 Will Soon Have a Real Linux Kernel](https://itsfoss.com/windows-linux-kernel-wsl-2/) it looks like you may not have too long to wait.

Comment: 2021 report: buildroot in WSL 2 works (not surpising..).. I came a long way.. `1.` Try with WSL1, `2.` try with Docker in WSL1 `3.` try with WSL2. Since it's possiblle to have WSL1 and 2 distros alongside, it is easy to use the advantages of both worlds..